# pre_get_posts with multiple queries

Tags: pre-get-posts

I have an archive template which I am using to list all businesses ("listings"), and also have pagination in place, however there is also a Google map, with custom markers for *all* the businesses.

How can I achieve this using the `pre_get_posts` function, since one query requires pagination, and the other (map) I have just set to 999 `posts_per_page`? Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

```
function listing_archive_custom_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive('listing') ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', get_option('posts_per_page') );
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'listing' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'featured' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
        $query->set( 'facetwp', true );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'listing_archive_custom_query' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two queries, one handling the listings, the other handling the map.

Since you need pagination for the listings, I'd suggest you use `pre_get_posts` for that query, so that you can use Wordpress' default pagination out of the box.

For the map, create a new WP_Query in your archive template:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'post_type' => 'listing',
);

$map = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: That's what I actually have in place at the moment, though I was hoping there would be another way since using `WP_query` to create a new query doesn't play well with another plugin I have - FacetWP. +1'd for now, but will leave this open just a bit longer before I accept.